# Failed to compile error when execute two functions when onChange is satisfied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I met this error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` when I designed the functionality of two inputs of date.

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState('');
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('');

const validDates = function() {
        //Get the text in the elements
        var from = document.getElementsByName('startDate').textContent;
        var to = document.getElementsByName('endDate').textContent;

        //Generate an array where the first element is the year, second is month and third is day
        var splitFrom = from.split('/');
        var splitTo = to.split('/');

        //Create a date object from the arrays
        var fromDate = Date.parse(splitFrom[0], splitFrom[1] - 1, splitFrom[2]);
        var toDate = Date.parse(splitTo[0], splitTo[1] - 1, splitTo[2]);

        if(fromDate < toDate) {
            document.getElementById('notice').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('notice').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('notice').innerHTML = "The End Date is supposed to be later than the Start Date!";
            document.getElementById('notice').innerHTML = '';
        }
    };

return (
<input type="date" name="startDate" defaultValue={experienceToEdit.start_date} onChange={e => {setStartDate(e.target.value); validDates}} value={startDate}></input>
<input type="date" name="endDate" defaultValue={experienceToEdit.end_date} onChange={e => {setEndDate(e.target.value); validDates}} value={endDate}></input>
<p id="notice"></p>
)
```

The error occurs in the `onChange` functionality of the input blocks. What I am going to do is to make sure the result of the second input block is later than the first one.

Comment: Is it possible you need to wrap your return statement in a single element? `return(<div>{content}</div>)`

Comment: Actually this isn't what I use in my real code, I just simplify to show what my problem is. The structure is more complicated than it was shown. It looks like a solution, let me take a shot.

Comment: It doesn't work though.

Comment: execute validDates function, like `validDates()`

Answer (score 1):

OnChange expects a callback, you're passing out a callback like this `onChange={e => {setStartDate(e.target.value); validDates}}`

Lets write the function you're giving onChange in another way

```
function a(e){
   setStartDate(e.target.value);
   validDates
}
```

this way tou can clearly see what's wrong with your code, validDates isn't being executed and react throws you an error